# How to retrieve user data from firebase? when we don't know about user name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to android development please if any one can help me with my problem.

Here is my firebase database json structure.

```
{
  "W10291JhlK32329Fgghk93293Hjg": {
    "mobile": 2390382094,
    "name": "efg"
  },
  "W4H6LWlQNMbKGlt1k8skI1WCoyQ2": {
    "mobile": 123456789,
    "name": "abc"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve like that:

```
FirebaseDatabase ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getreference("users").
```

Now I don't know how to go further b/c I don't know the username as it is auto generated so can anyone please help me with the exact code.

I want to fetch the mobile no from the firebase. Please if any one can help with the exact code so I can complete my task. I tried various YouTube videos but nothing worked it's continuously showing null pointer exception so please if any one can give me the exact code to fetch mobile no I will be grateful.

What I'm trying to do:
Basically I'm registering user by taking its phone no with otp authentication. Now when the user trying to login his account again I want to check that is the user is already registered by checking its entered phone number whether a user with this phone number exists or not if exists so I will move the user further. I just want to fetch the mobile no of each user so that I can compare each number with the user entered number.

Thanks.

Note: The code should be in java not in kotlin.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, do you need to get a single user or all users?

Comment: You want `mobile_no` of specific user? if so, what is the identifier?

Comment: I have added json structure as well and adds more description about what I'm actually trying to do. I hope it will clear all doubts so now can you look over my problem.

Comment: Usernames are not auto-generated (as mentioned in the question). You are probably referring to the user id aka `uid` which are auto-generated. When the user was created, you probably used the users `uid` to create the structure shown in the question with the node key being the uid. When a user authenticates again the authentication code returns and Auth object what contains the users uid. You can then use that to read the specific node `/users/uid`. Reviewing the docs [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) may provide additional help.